# Converting this to an aggregate function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aggregate, eager-loading

I am using the repository pattern + entity framework for a small project I'm working on. I needed to cut out lazy loading for performance reasons, but now I also need to include child entities in my db fetches. My current (working) solution is this:

```
    protected MediaDbEntities MediaDb { get { return db ?? (db = DatabaseFactory.Get()); } }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> All(string[] childEntities = null)
    {
        var query =  MediaDb.Set<T>();
        foreach (var childEntity in childEntities)
        {
            query.Include(childEntity);
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

I would really like to explore the use of an aggregate in this case, but don't really know how to apply. I have only used aggregates for sums and arithmetic operations. Anybody have an answer I can learn from?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you're not actually aggregating any data so trying to create any sort of aggregate is the wrong answer.

There's nothing wrong with your current solution. It makes perfect sense the way it is and I, personally, would leave it the way it is.